# Convert RDD having List of HashMap data to a dataFrame

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am writing a code to flat an XML in spark without com.databricks utility.

I have written a function where am converting XML to List>. Later on which is getting stored to an RDD. Sample Code is given below

```
  JavaPairRDD<Integer, List> ones=  lines.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<LongWritable,Text>, Integer, List>() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        void PairFunction(){}
        public Tuple2<Integer, List> call(
                Tuple2<LongWritable, Text> t) throws Exception {

                        List<Map<String,String>> List_Vals = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
                        Map<String,String> vals = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
                        vals.put("Sequence", "1234");
                        vals.put("customer", "1234");
                        temp++;
                        List_Vals.add(vals);
                        Map<String,String> val2 = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
                        val2.put("Sequence", "5678");
                        val2.put("customer", "ABCDE");
                        List_Vals.add(val2);
                    return new Tuple2<Integer, List>(temp, List_Vals);  
        }
    });
```

If I do ones.collect(); I am getting the below output

```
 [(1,[{Sequence=1234, customer=1234}, {Sequence=5678, customer=ABCDE}])
```

But I am looking to get the output in the format

```
  SrN, Sequence, customer
  1,   1234    , 1234
  1,   5678    , ABCDE
```

I am not able to identify a way to get this output. Kindly help

Comment: You dont have to use Tuple2, you can use Tuple3, and you can place temp, sequence, customer everything in one Tuple3.

Comment: also what you are doing inside `mapToPair` is adding two customer records, thats why you need a list, otherwise you can write as next record.

Comment: since you are using Java API, and `mapToPair`, you cannot return Tuple3 as mapToPair return type, what you can do is apply `map` and then you can return as Tuple3.